# Разбить строку на подстроки и записать в переменные

Tags: c#

Есть переменная:

```
string value1 = "5547.094158";
```

Как разбить эту строку в такой вид?:

```
string value2 = "55";
string value3 = "47.094158";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string value2 = value1.Substring(0, 2); // с начала строки берём 2 символа
string value3 = value1.Substring(2); // берём со 2-го символа и до конца строки, не забываем, что нумерация сущностей в C# обычно начинается с нуля
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value1 = "5547.094158";
        string value2 = value1.Substring(0, 2);
        string value3 = value1.Substring(2);
        MessageBox.Show("Строка 1 = "+ value2 + "  Строка 2 = " + value3);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ну меня уже опередили